# Need to optimize if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, optimization

I make a currency converter and as a result it turns out that the condition operators are almost identical, it would be better to somehow optimize through the ternary operator

```js
var exchan=document.getElementById("exchan");
exchan.addEventListener("click",function(e){
 var numberOne=document.getElementById("numberOne").value;
 var numberTwo=document.getElementById("numberTwo");
 var sExchange;
 var currencyOne=document.getElementById("currencyOne").value;
 var currencyTwo=document.getElementById("currencyTwo").value;
 if(currencyOne=="UAH" && currencyTwo=="USD"){
 numberTwo.value=(numberOne/cursUSD).toFixed(2);
 }
 if(currencyOne=="UAH" && currencyTwo=="EUR"){
 numberTwo.value=(numberOne/cursEUR).toFixed(2);
 }
 if(currencyOne=="UAH" && currencyTwo=="PLN"){
 numberTwo.value=(numberOne/cursPLN).toFixed(2);
 }

},false);
```

Comment: If currencyOne is UAH, will `currencyTwo` always be one of those three? USD, EUR, PLN? (that'll simplify the logic)

Comment: Why would the conditional operator be more "optimised"?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Later i want to add
USD to UAH
EUR to UAH...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the check for 'currencyOne' on the top part, since all your check require it, and it will evaluate once.
You can create a variable to hold the value of the operation, since the onlything changing is the value of the currencyTwo, so that you only have one line of 'numberTwo.value' assignment. You could use a switch if the if/else does not suite you for the inner checkings

```
 var curOperator;
    if(currencyOne=="UAH")
    {
     if(currencyTwo=="USD") curOperator = cursUSD; 
     else if(currencyTwo=="EUR") curOperator = cursEUR;  
     else if(currencyTwo=="PLN") curOperator = cursPLN; 
     else
        throw;
    }

    numberTwo.value=(numberOne/curOperator).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of standalone variables `cursUSD`, `cursEUR`, etc, onsider using an object indexed by the currency abbreviation. Then, just look up the conversion factor on the object:

```
const conversions = {
  USD: <value of cursUSD>,
  EUR: <value of cursEUR>,
  PLN: <value of cursPLN>
};
const exchan = document.getElementById("exchan");
exchan.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const [numberOneVal, currencyOneVal, currencyTwoVal] = ['numberOne', 'currencyOne', 'currencyTwo']
    .map(id => document.getElementById(id).value);
  if (currencyOneVal === "UAH" && conversions[currencyTwoVal]) {
    document.getElementById("numberTwo").value = (numberOneVal / conversions[currencyTwoVal]).toFixed(2);
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: I'd even go with a lookup table with two dimensions so, you'd do something like `if (lookup[currencyOne]) exchangeRate = lookup[currencyOne][currencyTwo]` That way you don't need extra logic to check if you can convert *from* something *to* another - you just need the lookup table to be filled in properly. And that can come from a file and/or generated, too - if you have the exchange rate for `UAD -> USD` you can compute the reverse and fill in the table.